# insertar un valor por defecto en mongodb - nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

tengo el siguiente formulario:

Codigo: 
            
          
          
            Nombre encargado: 
            
          
          
            Especialidad
            
                      Seleccionar
                        Traumatología
                        Odontología
                        Medicina interna
                        Oftalmología
                    
          
          
            Consultorio
            
          
          
            
            Registrar

Al enviar el registro al siguiente esquema en mongodb,no tengo idea de como crear un campo status por defecto que sea 'false'. como en el siguiente esquema:

new Schema({
  cod_history: {type: String, required: true},
  name_person: {type: String, required: true},
  specialty: {type: String. required: true},
  office: {type: String, required: true},
  status: false
})

Comment: Hola, imagino que usas Mongoose, ¿verdad?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba:

status: {type: Boolean, default: false}

Aquí puedes ver ya la solución en otro hilo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934901/9898836

Comment: favor de leer [answer], responder solo con código se considera de baja calidad, por favor edita y explica como esto soluciona el problema